# cx_freeze .exe not opening tkinter window

Tags: python, cx-freeze, win32gui

I am new to both Python and Stack Overflow, so I'm not very experienced at asking questions, but I've been searching this site for over two hours and I still can't find a solution to my problem. I have downloaded cx_freeze and have created my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os
import tkinter

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
base = None


executables = [Executable("Bounce.py", base=base)]

packages = ["tkinter"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages': ["os", "tkinter"],
    },

}

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'

includes = []
include_files = 
[r"C:\Users\peeps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",

r"C:\Users\peeps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll"]

setup(
    name = "Bounce",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Test",
    options = options,
    executables = executables
)
```

My actual python program runs with the tkinter module, and I tested the same process I tried with this with a non-tkinter python file, which was converted to a .exe flawlessly. When I run this setup.py using cx_freeze to convert Bounce.py to a .exe, the .exe program opens and instantly closes. The Bounce.py file prints nothing to the console, so I'm not sure whether or not the window that opens is for the console or the tkinter window (although the window size is that of the console and not of the tkinter window which I specified to 500 by 400 px) because it closes too quickly. Interestingly enough, when I change the setup.py file's system platform specification:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
base = None
```

to:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
base = 'Win32GUI'
```

like some of the guides say, I actually get an error message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA7ZG.png

I have no clue what that error message means or why it is happening. If you have any thoughts at all on how to fix this, please let me know. I feel like I've searched every forum and I'm the first with this problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Ah did you ever find that you just created `include_files` instead of using it?!

I am sure you must search for a lot of information before asking.Because you have known that `tcl8.6.dll` and `tk86t.dll` should be added to help tkinter run(So I am not prepared to explain more).

In fact, you just need to put `includes` and `include_files` into `build_exe`.

Here's my code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os
import tkinter

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"


executables = [Executable("Bounce.py", base=base)]

packages = ["tkinter"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': ["os", "tkinter"],
        'include_files': [r"C:\Users\peeps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                          r"C:\Users\peeps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\DLLs\tk86t.dll"]
    },

}

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python36\tcl\tk8.6'


setup(
    name="Bounce",
    version="1.0",
    description="Test",
    options=options,
    executables=executables
)
```

Finally, I advise you change `packages` into `includes` that works better than `packages`

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I would like to use `PyInstaller` but `cx_Freeze`

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The issue was that I had include_files and includes as variables except they weren't actually being used. I copied your program and it worked flawlessly (I did have to change the include_files to a different DLLs directory, but that was the only difference). I don't know if this is worthy of a whole separate post, but I wanted to know if there was a way to get rid of this error message that pops up after exiting my program: [link]http://i.imgur.com/hGzT6eP.png It is the error message printed to the console when tkinter is closed, but it isn't actually an "error"

Comment: I don't know what you changed `include_files` into(Because it works well on my machine).You can try to run your script with the python terminal instead of Anaconda(I truly know almost nothing useful about Anaconda) before adjusting the code.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what exactly the issue is, but if I'm turning a tkinter file into a .exe, I might just have to deal with a weird exit message. Anyways, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I consider you can use `PyInstaller` if necessary.It is much easier than `cx_Freeze` and never raised weird prompt when running.